# VB.NET Loop count Authors for each book

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach

I want to count the number of Author for each book in a table.
The result I have isn't correct.

### Table Title_AuthorTest:

ISBN    Au_ID2
Book1 - Author1,
Book2 - Author2,
Book2 - Author3,

### Result - after running code:

2 Books with 1 Authors,
0 Books with 2 Authors,
0 Books with 3 Authors,
...

### The result should be:

1 Books with 1 Authors,
1 Books with 2 Authors,
0 Books with 3 Authors,
...

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim BooksConnection As OleDbConnection
        Dim ISBNCommand As OleDbCommand
        Dim ISBNAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ISBNTable As DataTable
        'connect to books database
        BooksConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BooksDB.mdb;")
        BooksConnection.Open()
        'establish Command object
        ISBNCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Title_AuthorTest ORDER BY ISBN", BooksConnection)
        'establish data adapter / data table
        ISBNAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        ISBNAdapter.SelectCommand = ISBNCommand
        ISBNTable = New DataTable()
        ISBNAdapter.Fill(ISBNTable)
        'count authors
        Dim Author As Integer
        Dim AuthorCount(10) As Integer 'make array
        Dim LastISBN As String
        LastISBN = ""

        'allow up to 10 authors per title
        For Author = 1 To 10
            AuthorCount(Author) = 0 'set authorcount for all the authors to zero
        Next Author
        'set to the first author
        Author = 1

        'check each row for repeated ISBN
        Dim MyRow As DataRow
        'LastISBN = ISBNTable.Rows(0)("ISBN").ToString 'get first ISBN
        For Each MyRow In ISBNTable.Rows 'loop the table
            If MyRow.Item("ISBN").Equals(LastISBN) Then
                'is ISBN repeated then add Author
                Author += 1
            Else
                'no more authors for this ISBN
                AuthorCount(Author) += 1
                Author = 1
                LastISBN = MyRow.Item("ISBN").ToString 'zet LastISBN op ISBN die je net hebt geconsulteerd
            End If
        Next
        'display results number of books with x authors
        For Author = 1 To 10
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Str(AuthorCount(Author)) + " Books with" + Str(Author) + " Authors")
        Next
        'dispose
        BooksConnection.Close()
        BooksConnection.Dispose()
        ISBNCommand.Dispose()
        ISBNAdapter.Dispose()
        ISBNTable.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So, if a book has two authors you have two rows in the table? This is not the correct way to represent the relationship book->author. You should have a table for authors and a table that represent the relationship between book and authors. This table contains the ISBN and the foreign key to the authors table

Comment: I have always coded in this manner: `For Each MyRow as DataRow In ISBNTable.Rows`, and drop the line with the `Dim`.  In your way, I might be wrong but MyRow seems like it would only be a new row the very first time.  My way, it's always a new row.  I am not sure if this would change anything, but it was the first thing that jumped out at me.  And I might be wrong about how the `for` statement handles the variable.

Comment: Something seems wrong in your use of variable `Author`. I suggest creating new var's `CurrentISBN` and `AuthorsPerISBN` that are more clear about their purpose and re-code.

Comment: @technonaut
I figured out there would probably be an issue with Author.  
Can you help me fix it?  I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start changing the SQL command and use a GROUP BY

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT ISBN, COUNT(ISBN) as NrAuthors from Title_AuthorTest 
               GROUP BY ISBN
               ORDER BY COUNT(ISBN) DESC"

ISBNCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, BooksConnection)
```

Now you have all books grouped on their ISBN and each record contains the ISBN and the number of authors for that ISBN.
At this point your code could be greatly simplified with

```
For Each MyRow as DataRow In ISBNTable.Rows 
    Dim numAuthors As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(MyRow("NrAuthors"))
    AuthorCount(numAuthors) += 1
Next
```

Of course this will allow a book written by a max of 10 authors. If there is a book written by more than 10 authors we need to check before indexing the AuthorCount array or change the way we store this information using a different structure

Comment: thanks, it works!
I still don't understand where I went wrong in my foreach-statement

Comment: To discover what is wrong with your actual code the best path is to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint before entering the row loop and you will see that Author variable is indexing the wrong place in the array

Comment: Be sure to click the "accept answer" checkmark if you like the solution, so they get credit for helping solve your problem.

Comment: I'll try.  Thanks!